# WHERE statement is excluding nulls need to include nulls and failed matches

Tags: sql

For the code below the part the second part of the where statement (after and) is excluding everything where d.CreditRating is null. The statement is needed to chose the most recent date and match by only one of c.ISIN,c.SEDOL,c.CUSIP. How can I make it include where credit rating is null because we are unable to match or the actual value is null?

The query works when only everything before the and statement in where is run, but then it doesn't choose the most recent date. Thanks.

```
Select e.MSPortfolioId,
       b.PortfolioId,
       c.DetailHoldingTypeId,
       d.CreditRating,
       b.MarketValue,
       c.SecurityId,
       c.ISIN,
       c.SEDOL,
       c.CUSIP
From   PortfolioCoreData.dbo.LatestPortfolio e
Left Join HoldingData.dbo.HoldingDetail b
    On e.LatestStoredPortfolioId = b.PortfolioId
Left Join HoldingData.dbo.SecurityInfo c
    On b.SecurityId = c.SecurityId
Left Join BondData.dbo.BondCreditRating d
    On (Case When c.CUSIP Is Not Null Then c.CUSIP
             When c.ISIN Is Not Null Then c.ISIN
             Else c.SEDOL End) = d.BondId
Where  e.MSPortfolioId In ( '5670', '4404', '5973', '861996' )
       And (d.EffectiveDate = ( Select Max(d.EffectiveDate)
                                  From   BondData.dbo.BondCreditRating d
                                  Where  (Case When c.CUSIP Is Not Null Then c.CUSIP   When c.ISIN Is Not Null Then c.ISIN  When c.SEDOL Is Not Null Then c.SEDOL  End ) = d.BondId ));
```

Comment: It's excluding nulls because the `WHERE` statement executes *after* the `LEFT JOIN`.  If you want to keep the `NULL` values from the `OUTER JOIN` you need to include those conditions in the `ON` clause.

Comment: Show us db schema, sample data and expected output. 
 Please read [**How-to-Ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
 
 And here is a great place to [**START**](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) to learn how improve your question quality and get better answers.

 [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: BTW: `Case When c.CUSIP Is Not Null Then c.CUSIP When c.ISIN Is Not Null Then c.ISIN When c.SEDOL Is Not Null Then c.SEDOL End` is simply `COALESCE(c.CUSIP, c.ISIN, c.SEDOL)`.

Comment: Alias names should *enhance* readability. e, b, c, d don't. Use mnemonics instead, e.g. `lp` for `LatestPortfolio` and `hd` for `HoldingDetail`.

Comment: Why do you compare MSPortfolioId with strings? Isn't this ID numeric?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This occurs because your query selects only EffectiveDate if values, to add EffectiveDate is null you need to ask it too.

You can try this where

```
Where  e.MSPortfolioId In ( '5670', '4404', '5973', '861996' )
       And 
       (
        (d.EffectiveDate = (
                                  Select Max(d.EffectiveDate)
                                  From   BondData.dbo.BondCreditRating d
                                  Where  (Case When c.CUSIP Is Not Null Then c.CUSIP
                                               When c.ISIN Is Not Null Then c.ISIN
                                               When c.SEDOL Is Not Null Then c.SEDOL
                                          End
                                         ) = d.BondId
                              )
           ) OR d.EffectiveDate is null);
```

Comment: While this works, it is still not a good answer. This is a join condition and should hence be in the `ON` clause. Then `OR d.EffectiveDate is null` would not be necessary.